# Animated progress bar in NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, pyobjc, nsmenuitem

I want to put an animated progress bar in an `NSMenuItem` custom view. This is demonstrated in Apple's *MenuItemView* sample, but it doesn't animate (at least not in 10.5, and the sample is apparently from 10.4).

I have tried setting a timer that calls `setNeedsDisplay:YES`, scheduled as `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` like the docs say. This works, but only for a determinate progress bar if I change the value, and only the first time the menu opens. The second and successive times, the bar redraws twice and then remains frozen. For an indeterminate progress bar, the barber pole stripes never animate.

---

Edit: code snippet. I just added the `itemChanged` call, which didn't seem to have any effect. Updating the text-only item works fine.

```
class AppDelegate(NSObject):
  barItem = None
  menuProgressBar = None
  progressItem = None

  def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
    statusbar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()
    self.statusitem = statusbar.statusItemWithLength_(
        NSSquareStatusItemLength)
    self.statusitem.setHighlightMode_(True)
    image = NSImage.imageNamed_("menubar.png")
    self.statusitem.setImage_(image)
    self.statusitem.retain()

    menu = NSMenu.alloc().init()

    AppDelegate.barItem = NSMenuItem.alloc(). \
        initWithTitle_action_keyEquivalent_('progress', None, '')
    itemView = NSView.alloc().initWithFrame_(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 20))
    itemView.setAutoresizingMask_(NSViewWidthSizable)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar = \
        NSProgressIndicator.alloc().initWithFrame_(NSMakeRect(16, 5, 22, 10))
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.setAutoresizingMask_(NSViewWidthSizable)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.setControlSize_(NSSmallControlSize)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.setUsesThreadedAnimation_(True)
    itemView.addSubview_(AppDelegate.menuProgressBar)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.setIndeterminate_(False)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.setMaxValue_(100)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.startAnimation_(self)
    timer = NSTimer.timerWithTimeInterval_target_selector_userInfo_repeats_(
        0.1, self,
        objc.selector(self.animateProgress, signature='v@:'),
        None, True)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer_forMode_(
        timer, NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode)
    AppDelegate.barItem.setView_(itemView)
    menu.addItem_(AppDelegate.barItem)

    AppDelegate.progressItem = NSMenuItem.alloc(). \
        initWithTitle_action_keyEquivalent_('Progress', None, '')
    menu.addItem_(AppDelegate.progressItem)

    self.statusitem.setMenu_(menu)

  def animateProgress(self):
    time = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.setDoubleValue_(time%100)
    AppDelegate.menuProgressBar.display()
    AppDelegate.progressItem.setTitle_('Progress: %d'%(time%100))
    AppDelegate.barItem.menu().itemChanged_(AppDelegate.barItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

The timer approach should be completely unnecessary. Have you told the NSProgressIndicator to -setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES then told it to -startAnimation:?

Comment: Yes, I did those as well. No effect.

Comment: I don't recognize the syntax. I'm guessing you're not using Objective-C?

Comment: This is Python, using PyObjC. I'm new to it myself, but I find it pretty easy to adjust.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you. :-) I'll have to turn this over to the community.

Answer (score 1):

For an indeterminate indicator I send the startAnimation: message in the menu's menuWillOpen: delegate method using performSelector:... to send it in the NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode mode.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu
{
  [[progressIndicator performSelector:@selector(startAnimation:)
                           withObject:self
                           afterDelay:0.0
                              inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode]];
}
```

For the determinate indicator I tried your code (but in objective-C) and it worked. I don't know python or PyObjC but looking at the code for the time variable I think you are sending the timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() call to the NSDate class. So maybe time is always zero? Based on the alloc() calls I wonder if it shouldn't be ...

> time = NSDate.date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

---

Update: for the record here is the code I used for testing the determinate progress indicator. Just obj-c version of the OP's code. The indicator updates properly.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu
{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(animateProgress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)animateProgress:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSTimeInterval time = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    [progressIndicator setDoubleValue:fmod(time, 100)];
}
```

Comment: The NSDate call works fine. The determinate progress bar works the first time the menu opens, and the text-only item always works. I'll try subclassing NSView so I can override menuWillOpen.

Comment: I mean, I'll try doing the delegate thing.