# Objective-C, how to display determinate progress bar?

Tags: objective-c, methods, progress-bar

I would like to show the progress bar in my app as determinate rather than indeterminate. It doesn't work though when setting it up as determinate (works just fine for indeterminate). I've [read some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089555/animated-progress-bar-in-nsmenuitem) of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784230/displaying-file-copy-progress-using-fscopyobjectasync) answers to this, although they haven't worked. Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {

    IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *showProgress;

}

- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender {

    [showProgress setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];   // This works
    [showProgress startAnimation:self];            // This works
    [showProgress setDoubleValue:(0.1)];           // This does not work
    [showProgress setIndeterminate:NO];            // This does not work

    [self doSomething];
    [self doSomethingElse];
    [self doSomethingMore];
    ....

    [barProgress setDoubleValue:(1.0)];            // This does not work
    [barProgress stopAnimation:self];              // This works

}
```

---

Updated code [working]:

```
- (IBAction)someMethod:(id)sender {

    [showProgress setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];
    [showProgress startAnimation:self];
    [showProgress setIndeterminate:NO];

    [showProgress setDoubleValue:(0.1)];
    [showProgress startAnimation:nil];

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [barProgress incrementBy:10.0];
            });
        }

    [self doSomething];

            [showProgress incrementBy:...];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [showProgress stopAnimation:nil];

        });
    });

    [showProgress setDoubleValue:(1.0)];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `doSomething` method is blocking the main thread, which causes the run loop not to cycle, which in turn causes UI redraw to be blocked. The fix is to do the long running work in `doSomething` on a background queue, with periodic callbacks to the main queue to update the progress bar.

I have no idea what your `doSomething` method does, but for the sake of explanation, let's assume it runs a for loop with 100 steps. You'd implement it something like this:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
    [showProgress startAnimation:nil];
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // Do whatever it is you need to do

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [showProgress incrementBy:1.0];
            });
        }
        // Done with long running task
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [showProgress stopAnimation:nil];
        });
    });
}
```

Keep in mind, you still need to set the progress indicator up to be determinate, initialize its value and set an appropriate minValue and maxValue.

If you must do the work in `doSomething` on the main thread, it's possible to schedule small chunks of that work to be done on each run loop cycle, or to manually spin the run loop periodically as you're doing the work, but Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) would be my first choice if you can use it.

Comment: — awesome example. I updated my question to reflect the working version with your code example; let me know if i'm missing anything or you see any issues. ty again ;-)

Comment: Hi — I've got a quick question about this again. The progress bar was working fine when it was associated with a button that started the animation. However I no longer need the button, and the animation no longer starts even with parameters such as `[showProgress startAnimation:self];` Any ideas?

Comment: You'd have to post your new code for me to give any suggestions. Are you blocking the main thread again? I'd suggest posting a new question with your new code.

Comment: No, the code isn't new at all — it simply eliminates having a (IBAction) instead of void (which is the method you show). I switched it to void and now the progressbar is no longer showing (or progressing). Is there something special that I'm missing possibly? thanks.You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: IBAction is simply a #define for void (see AppKit/NSNibDeclarations.h), so if that's really the only change you made, your compiled executable will be _exactly_ the same. How are you calling the method now, if not from a button? Changing how the method is called is very possibly the cause of the new behavior. Changing IBAction -> void in and of itself means nothing.

Comment: i think when i broke one of my methods into two it had some effect on it. if there's an extra method now before calling doSomething would i need to change the dispatch to go one more thread deep possibly? thanks again.

Comment: I have no idea without seeing your code. I'd really encourage you to post a new question. Comment with a link here so I can find it.

Comment: i figured it out; my method was accidentally copied twice and it was attached to 'the other one' heh. thanks again - works good. +1